# Match major.minor.revision-SNAPSHOT with regex

Tags: regex

I'm new in regex and I want one that matches this pattern:

```
major.minor.revision-SNAPSHOT
```

where major, minor and revision are numbers of one or more digits.

Examples:

```
`1.2.0-SNAPSHOT` must match
`165.2.23-SNAPSHOT` must match
`165.2.20` must not match
`165.2.20-` must not match
```

I have tried this one:

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)[-](-SNAPSHOT)?.*
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Just add anchors `^` and `$` to regex. `^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)[-](-SNAPSHOT)?.*$`. If you don't want the matches capturing groups can be removed `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+[-]-SNAPSHOT?.*$`

Comment: `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-SNAPSHOT$`

Comment: the only 2 problems in your regex are: 1. `[-]`, remove it. 2. `(-SNAPSHOT)?` should become `-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The right regex is `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-SNAPSHOT$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `\d*[.]\d*[.]\d*[-]SNAPSHOT` - it takes ~0ms to execute. [Tested in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MLlcWG/1).